# Apache Avro schema-less writing to file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro

I want to write multiple Avro serialized objects to file. However, I do not want the schema, as shown below:

[image]

Another program will read this file with a-priori knowledge of the schema and deserialize each object.

How can I do this with Python 3? I have solved each problem separately but not in conjunction, I have only seen a solution to this but using Java and I cannot transpose it to Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [`fastavro.schemaless_writer`](https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writer.html#fastavro._write_py.schemaless_writer)

Comment: In the documentation you link it says "Note: The schemaless_writer can only write a single record." - does this mean one record per call, or one record per file?

Comment: One per call and one record per file. Theoretically you could write additional schemaless records to the same file, but you would need code in place to break the file back apart into single records when using the `schemaless_reader` as it expects just a single record.